# WAMP automatically adds .php extension to file with RewriteRule

Tags: php, wamp

I am trying to rewrite my url with apache .htaccess (rewriting) as following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My small project structure is:

- .htaccess
- index.php
- test.php

Everything works fine, whatever I type after the "/" is in my *$_GET["url"]* variable. But as soon as I type in domain.com/index, it somehow automatically adds the .php extension to my url and leaves my *$_GET["url"]* empty. Same story when I try domain.com/test: it goes to *test.php* instead of rewriting to *domain.com/url=test*.

The strangest thing is that on 000webhost.com it all works perfectly! When I upload the same file(s), its shows up the *index* and *test* in my *$_GET["url"]* variable.

Hope someone can help me!
Gratz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because the `Multiviews` option was enabled. Removing this one fixed the problem.